# Put a variable into a variable

Tags: javascript

I have this variable

```js
var qStartday = '2017-02-22T22:00,
```

How i can get curent date and i add one month to my automated script?

Comment: start by creating a vlid string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date('2017-02-22T22:00');
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1)
console.log(d);
```

Comment: this is how you use the Date object. also, no need to worry adding more than 12 months, it automatically adjusts the year

Comment: But how to replace 2017-02-22T22:00 by curent day?

Comment: I have an automated test case who need to enter a date automaticly, so i need a variable to get curent date yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm and add 2 months every time.

Comment: var currentdate = new Date(); // - return current date

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);

work fine for me